# Calculations in acrobat

Tags: javascript

I want to calculate a value entered in one field with a set amount - my coding is below but it returns a value of NaN

```
if (this.getField("Qty FP_NW").value >= 1) {
   event.value = ("Qty FP_NW" * "$454.25") ;
} else {
   event.value = " " ;
}
```

Do I need to set up a text field for the $454.25 value?

Comment: You can't do calculations with strings

Answer (score 0):

You must calculate with numbers. Assuming your `Qty` is a number you can do this.

```
quantityVal = this.getField("Qty FP_NW").value;
if (quantityVal  >= 1) {
   event.value = (quantityVal  * 454.25) ;
} else {
   event.value = " " ;
}
```